# Commentaries on Abhinavgupta's Tantraloka translated to English

Tags: advaita, reference-request, kashmiri-shaivism, abhinavagupta, trika

In the school of Kashmir Shivaism, if I'm not wrong, then both texts - Abhinavgupta's Tantraloka and Vigyaan Bhairava Tantra belong to Spanda Doctrine (please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm very ignorant) of Trika school of Kashmir.

Are there any good commentaries on both explaining them in Spanda Doctrine in English?

Comment: Five volume set along with English and Sanskrit commentary https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/sri-tantraloka-of-abhinavgupta-nan899/

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay That works! :)

Comment: If you want a free version of the English translation of the Tantraloka, you can get it from the internet archive. However, the commentary is not part of this edition. This is 8 volume set. All volumes are freely available. https://archive.org/details/sri-tantraloka-4/Sri%20Tantraloka%201/mode/1up

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay Thank you so much for that. That is really helpful. In case you are able to write an answer, I would really upvote and accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jayaratha wrote a commentary on Abhinavgupta's Tantraloka. An English translation is available. This edition is published by Chaukhamba Surbharati Prakashan and translated by Giriratna Mishra. However, this is not free and this is a hardcopy. It is a five-volume set available from Exotic India. Here is the link -

https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/sri-tantraloka-of-abhinavgupta-nan899/

However, a free version of the English translation of the Tantraloka is available in the internet archive. However, the commentary is not part of this edition. This is an eight volume set, translated by Professor Satya Prakash Singh and Swami Maheshvarananda. All volumes are freely available. Here is the link -

https://archive.org/details/sri-tantraloka-4/Sri%20Tantraloka%201/mode/1up

Comment: Thank You so much. I accepted the answer. :)